# Injecting different providers while loading components using ComponentResolver in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-injection

Can we inject different provider while loading components dynamically?

**my-component**

```
  @Component({
     moduleId: module.id,
     selector: "my-component",
     template: "<div>my-component</div>",
     providers: [MyComponentService]
  })
  export class MyComponent{

     constructor(private ds: MyComponentService) {
        super();
     }    
   }
```

some where else,

```
     this._cr.resolveComponent(MyComponent).then(cmpFactory => {
        let instance: any = this.testComponentContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory).instance;
    });
```

so in above code, while resolving `MyComponent`, provider for this `MyComponentService` will also be resolved, can we resolve it differently based upon some switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ViewContainerRef.createComponent](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html)

```
createComponent(componentFactory: ComponentFactory<C>, index?: number, injector?: Injector, projectableNodes?: any[][]) : ComponentRef<C>
```

has an `injector` parameter. If you pass one this one is used to resolve providers. I don't think you can override providers added to the `@Component()` decorator though.

You can create a new injector [Injector](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ReflectiveInjector-class.html)

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Car, Engine])
```

and pass this injector or you can inject the injector to the component that calls `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` and create a child injector.

```
constructor(private injector:Injector) {}
```

`Injector` is the generic base class `ReflectiveInjector` is a concrete implementation.

```
let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([Car, Engine]);
let child = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedProviders, this.injector);
```

This way the providers that are available to the current component are passed along and `Car`, and `Child` are added. Therefore providers that `child` can't resolve (others than `Car` and `Engine`) are tried to resolve from the parent injector.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ts2QVNfaSQkrmKyJoT0r?p=preview)

Comment: so is it good to assume if i don't add provider parameter, and use injector then component factory will inject MyComponentService while loading component dynamically?

Comment: I had expected that the parent injector would be passed along when none is passed (not tested). If this doesn't work then just inject it to the current component and forward it to `createComponent(...)` or if you want add additional providers, then create a child injector.

Comment: when i try to use this.testComponentContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory,<what should i pass here as I already have the ViewContainerRef, it asks me to pass index if i pass 0 or null throws error>, injector). Any suggestions?

Comment: Plunker you have added is not working, I am seeing some console errors.

Comment: Sorry for that. The Plunker was broken in two ways. One was caused by me. The other seems to be caused by Angular updates. I updated the Plunker.