# When is Angular 2 Renderer provided?

Tags: angular

This is a small thing, but it's been bugging me. I can inject an instance of Renderer into a component and use it fine. What I don't understand is how this is working. As far as i could find in the source code, only DomRootRenderer_ is provided inside of Browser_App_Providers as RootRenderer. However, the actual implementation of Renderer is the DomRenderer class, which I could not find the provider for. So then how is the DI resolving Renderer? Is it calling the RenderComponent method on the DomRootRenderer_ somewhere? Can someone point me to the right location in the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a component is created, a new child injector of the parent components injector is created for the new component. When this child injector is created additional providers can be added. Angular2 does that with the `providers` and `viewProviders` you add to your `@Component()` decorator and it also adds a series of other providers like `ElementRef`, `ViewContainerRef`, `Injector`, the parent component, ...

How to create a child injector is for example shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37734641/217408

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DirectiveMetadata-class.html for how providers are resolved when a component instance is created.

Comment: I think i didn't phrase my question correctly, or maybe I'm just not understanding your answer. Basically I'm confused as to how the DI is resolving Renderer to the concrete class DomRenderer (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.ts#L58). The BrowserAppProvider (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/browser.ts#L64) is only providing DomRootRenderer and RootRenderer, both of which uses the same class DomRootRenderer_, I think? So when is DomRenderer provided as Renderer?

Comment: I haven't found where it's added to providers, but I assume it is what is returned from `DomRootRenderer.renderComponent()` (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3644eef860cdc31a22368acd48b0e657fd89f501/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.ts#L42)

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm assuming as well. It was just bugging me because both RootRenderer and DomRootRenderer were not provided with the useFactory so I didn't know when renderComponent was called. But like I said on the original post, not a big deal. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is from docs, `RootRenderer`:

```
   /** 
    * Injectable service that provides a low-level interface for modifying the UI.
     *
     * Use this service to bypass Angular's templating and make custom UI changes that can't be
     * expressed declaratively. For example if you need to set a property or an attribute whose name is
     * not statically known, use {@link #setElementProperty} or {@link #setElementAttribute}
     * respectively.
     *
     * If you are implementing a custom renderer, you must implement this interface.
     *
     * The default Renderer implementation is `DomRenderer`. Also available is `WebWorkerRenderer`.
     * @experimental
     */
    export abstract class RootRenderer {
      abstract renderComponent(componentType: RenderComponentType): Renderer;
    }
```