# Getting dependency from Injector manually inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a generic directive which will take a class type for rule validation and according to the rule in the class the directive will either show or hide an element.

This is my attempt so far.

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/GyDEUicFVVNt1AxywU2R?p=info) Demo

**myIf-Directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myIf]'
})
export class MyIfDirective {
  constructor(private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private _template: TemplateRef<Object>) 
  { }

  @Input() set myIf(rule: string) {
    //rule class type will come as string
    //how can I use string token to get dependency from injector?
    //currently harcoded
    //will the injector create new instance or pass on instance from parent?
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([AdminOnly]);
    let adminOnly : IRule = injector.get(AdminOnly);
    let show = adminOnly.shouldShowElement();
    show ? this.showItem() : this.hideItem();
  }
  private showItem() {
    this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._template);
  }

  private hideItem() {
    this._viewContainer.clear();
  }
}
```

**app-component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *myIf="'AdminOnly'">
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

But I am stuck in 2 places:

1. I keep getting the error `No Provider for AuthService`
2. I do not know how I can get the dependency from Injector using class name as string rather than the type

Any suggestion whether this is the right way to do it or where I am going wrong is highly appreciated.

Comment: *I do not know how I can get the dependency from Injector using class name as string rather than the type* You can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40063568/3731501

Comment: @estus So, is there anyway I can pass the type of `AdminOnly` to the `my-if` directive rather than as a string?

Comment: I'm not sure how this directive should work. But you have to pass component constructor function, not a string. If you want to pass it as a string, a map of components and their string representations should be used like it was shown above.

Comment: @estus Basically, what I am expecting is that I will send a rule class/type to the directive and it will get the instance from the injector with all its dependencies and invoke a certain method to determine whether to show or hide the element in question. If this is not possible could you recommend another suitable API for this to work?

Comment: You need to use an injector as the answer suggests and resolve a component through map. It doesn't look like a good design solution to me. I'm not sure what would be a good one. For limited amount of components it should be a template with `ngSwitch`, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the parent injector like

```
export class MyIfDirective {
  constructor(private injector:Injector, private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private _template: TemplateRef<Object>) 
  { }

  @Input() set myIf(rule: string) {
    let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([AdminOnly]);
    let childInjector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedProviders, this.injector);

    let adminOnly : IRule = childInjector.get(AdminOnly);
    let show = adminOnly.shouldShowElement();
    show ? this.showItem() : this.hideItem();
  }
  private showItem() {
    this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._template);
  }

  private hideItem() {
    this._viewContainer.clear();
  }
}
```

See also [Inject service with ReflectiveInjector without specifying all classes in the dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402169/inject-service-with-reflectiveinjector-without-specifying-all-classes-in-the-dep/40402201#40402201)

Comment: This solves No.1 of my problems. Thanks. Could you also suggest some option for the second problem?

Comment: You need to register it by string like `{provide: 'someName', useClass: SomeClass}`, then you can get it by name like `injector.get('someName')`. Alternatively you can maintain a map of types like `let types = {'someName': SomeClass', 'foo': Foo, 'bar': Bar}`, then you can use it like `injector.get(this.types['someName'])`

Comment: I like the first way. But in that case this will not work `let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(['AdminOnly']);`

Comment: `let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([{provide: 'AdminOnly', useClass: AdminOnly]);` or `let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([{provide: 'AdminOnly', useClass: this.types['AdminOnly']}]);`

Answer (score 0):

Just update for Angular version 10+:

- From your service:

```
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'any'
  })
  export class AdminOnly { ... }
```

- In your directive or a pure function, ...:

```
 import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

 ...
 const injector: Injector = Injector.create({
   providers: [{provide: AdminOnly, deps: []}]
 });
 const adminOnly: AdminOnly = injector.get(AdminOnly);

 let show = adminOnly.shouldShowElement();
 ...
```

[See more](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector)