# Send data from TS class to Angular component via service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-services

Outside of Angular project, there is a TS class from which I'm trying to send object to angular component via service.

`sender.ts` is TS class which sends object using Angular service;

```
export class Sender {

  injector;
  servicePointer;
  myData: Object;

  constructor() {

    this.injector = Injector.create({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ShareDataService,
          deps: []
        },
      ]
    });

    this.servicePointer = this.injector.get(ShareDataService);
  }

  public send() {
    this.myData = {
      name: "Robert",
      visible: true
    }

    return this.servicePointer.dataVisibility(this.myData);
  }
}
```

`share-data.service.ts` is an Angular service which successfully receives object from `sender.ts` class:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareDataService {

  changeDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});

  public dataUpdate$ = this.changeDataSource.asObservable();

  public dataVisibility = (dataInfo: Object) => {
    //console.log(dataInfo);
    this.changeDataSource.next(dataInfo);
  }
}
```

`app.component.ts` includes the `Sender` TS class and calls `.send()` method:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private foo:Sender.Sender = new Sender.Sender();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.foo.send();
  }
}
```

At least, there is a `receive` component which subscribes to the service:

```
export class ReceiverComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private shareDataService: ShareDataService) { }

  receivedData;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shareDataService.dataUpdate$.subscribe(success => {
      this.receivedData = success;
      console.log(this.receivedData);
    })
  }
}
```

and always returns empty object from the service, although object with data comes to the service (console.log(dataInfo)).

What could cause the problem? In the `service` there is

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
```

decorator with root application injector and in the `sender` class there is also an injector from service is provided. Could that might the problem? If so, is there another way to inject the service?
There is also a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-component-communication-service) with code explained above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject Service into class (not component)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432388/how-to-inject-service-into-class-not-component)

Comment: Why do you use `new` to get a reference to the Sender, and why do you use the injector to get an instance of ShareDataService in the sender? Sender should just be a service and use dependency injection.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm using `new` because of the instantiation of the class and injector is used because constructor injection is undefined. In the project Sender represents a class and cannot be a service.

Comment: Why couldn't it be a service?

Comment: I tried to tranform it to the service and result is the same [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-component-communication-service-wfeclk)

Comment: Just make it a service like your shared service... https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-component-communication-service-wfeclk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts I didn't look closely at the code, just changed the `Sender` service to a service... so I don't take responsibility if there is something that could be improved :D

Comment: @AJT_82 Do you mean on change `Sender` class to a service :)? That's exactly what I've done in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-component-communication-service-wfeclk)

Comment: Sorry, linked the wrong stackblitz :D I don't know what kinda attempt you made to make it a service. It should look just like your other service: https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-component-communication-service-wfeclk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: ...hmm... doesn't let me fork it correctly...

Comment: I had to make a new one... try now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-component-communication-service-v5tgg6?file=sender%2Fsender.ts

Comment: @AJT_82 The problem was in the sender instance... I've just made instantiation in the constructor of the AppComponent like you did :)