# When should I DI the Injector directly in an Angular app?

Tags: angular

By directly I mean like this:

```
constructor(private injector:Injector) {
  injector.get(MyService);
}
```

Currently I am using this syntax on base classes that require many dependencies in order to add to the constructor arguments without having to change the derived classes. Is this a bad approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems like there isn't a better way (best practice) to achive this.
as injections only works with classes instantiated by Angular's dependency injection (DI).

Refer to this  [How to inject Service into class (not component)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41433007/9369606)

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672311/9369606) as a workaround.