# APP_INITIALIZER - How to access enviroment properties in all classes?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the `APP_INITIALIZER` with `useFactory` for the configuration file to load environment properties as json file during the run time. It works and I can access the properties in different **components** and **services** using following code:

```
public propsConfiguration: PropsConfiguration;

constructor(
    private ConfigService: ConfigService,
    ...
) {
  this.propsConfiguration = this.configService.getConfiguration();
  this.urlAdd = this.propsConfiguration.propertyName;
}
....
....
```

My issue is that I cannot access the properties in this way in some other classes such:
**department.model.ts** which is actually just a model class with a constructor and one method. Have been trying couple of options but didn't help. How can I access the properties in such classes? Any Idea or hint please?

Comment: This is your solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432388/how-to-inject-service-into-class-not-component

Comment: @navnath: indeed. The answer from: Kilves did the fix. Don't know how to add here as an answer. Aynway, the issue is fixed with option from Kilves in the question/link you posted.