# Injecting and resolving angular2 providers by string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am trying to inject providers based on run time data to my angular2 component.

So far I have this:

```
  let type: PropertyDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(providers, provider.name);
  if (!type) return;

  let injector: Injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([(<any>type).get()]);
  let resolvedProvider: IAnalyticRepository = injector.get((<any>type).get());
```

This attemps to create the provider but because of its child dependencies it throws an error.

The error I receive is:

> Error: No provider for HttpHandler! (GoogleRepository -> HttpHandler)

How would I go on about injecting the child providers to the resolved provider as well?

Comment: What error? How is this related to "providers by string"?

Comment: I am trying to say that I am injecting dynamically. I'll edit the to add the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is to build an injector that also includes Angular2 providers when resolving

```
constructor(private injector:Injector) {}

...

someMethod() {    
  let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([Car, Engine]);
  let child = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(
      resolvedProviders, 
      this.injector
  );
}
```

See also [Inject service with ReflectiveInjector without specifying all classes in the dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402169/inject-service-with-reflectiveinjector-without-specifying-all-classes-in-the-dep/40402201#40402201)